# Two-way network communication with gawk with multi-line input

Tags: sockets, networking, gawk

I am trying to make a gawk program act as a simple server, bound to a network socket and answering queries.

My script so far is this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk

BEGIN {
    s="nc -l 10.0.0.21 2345";
    while (s |& getline inp) {
        print inp;
        print "Response to " inp |& s;
    }
}
```

You'll note that I'm using `netcat` instead of gawk's internal networking?  From my read of the documentation, I should theoretically be able to set `s="/inet/tcp/2345/0/0";` to have gawk bind to *every* local IP address on port 2345, but I gather that if I want to bind to just one IP (on a multi-IP host), I need to use something like what I've done.  Also, when I tested the `/inet/tcp/...` notation, I couldn't get it to work.  The script would run, and wait for input, but it didn't seem to bind to the socket, so it wouldn't get any input.

So ... with the netcat alternative working, my question is ... **how do I leave the server running, after the client closes the connection?**

With the code above, I can connect and send multiple lines which get responses, but as soon as the client disconnects, the server also exits.

I gather this is because the `nc` command line closes the input stream, and thus ends the while loop, but it seems to me that the while loop should just continue by re-opening the `s` variable as a co-process again.

How do I make this work?  Would this not be a problem if I could use the `/inet/tcp/...` notation?  Should I wrap the whole gawk script in a shell script that just re-runs it on exit?  Or should I wrap the inner while loop in another while loop?  Or something else?

I tried replacing the invocation of the while loop with this:

```
...
    while (1) {
        s |& getline inp;
        print inp;
...
```

but it exited in exactly the same way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there was quite a discussion on comp.lang.awk in the last year about gawk and 2-way communication. It will be worth your time searching in google-groups for it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

With [GNU `netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) you can use `-k` option to keep server running after client connection is closed. See [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).

Comment: Thanks, that *does* solve my problem. (+1) But can you explain why my `while (1) {` solution didn't reopen/restart netcat?

Answer (score 0):

Answering why your `while` solution doesn't work as you asked in the comments of the answer above, executing external commands (`command | getline...`) in awk require them to be "closed" before being invoked again (or this will try to continue reading the output from the original invocation -- even if the process dies --).

You will have to detect when the execution finishes (getline reads nothing) and execute a `close(s)`.  Only after executing the `close`, `s | getline` will run a new instance of the command.